# Unexpected Token: REGEXP from Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am getting this error while trying the REGEXP in HQL (Hibernate 3 + spring),

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: unexpected token: REGEXP
```

Is there any workaround to do this? (I should use REGEXP in my queries) and I am using HibernateTemplate of Spring.

Thanks

Comment: how about showing us the query?

Comment: @Ralph sorry, wrong question. Another one was a duplicate of that :)